# What do I have to do to get my router path working?

Tags: reactjs

I can't get my Router working in react. I am using `webpack`, thinking I miss some code in `webpacn.config.js.`

I tried to retype my url to `localhost:8080/signin` or `localhost:8080/signup`.

I got en error of

> Cannot GET /signin

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import Navbar from './Components/layout//Navbar'
import SignIn from './Components/authentication/SignIn'
import SignUp from './Components/authentication/SignUp'
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super()
}
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
                        <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your node server, can you post your node server file? And give some details about what you use for your node server.

Comment: If you are guessing that problem is in your webpack configuration why you didn't paste it here? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not related to Webpack. react's router system handles the routes in client-side so if you want to type URL manually, you should create a fallback URL to root path in the back-end side (based on your back-end tech) then react can handle entered URL.